# How to prove $\Vert\mathbb{E}[X]\Vert\leq \mathbb{E}[\Vert X\Vert]?$

Tags: inequality, expected-value

i encounter a quesition as follows when i read the Appendix of the paper which link is https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.00743

$$
\Vert \mathbb{E}_{x^\prime\in A(x)}[f(x^\prime)]\Vert \leq \mathbb{E}_{x^\prime \in A(x)}[\Vert f(x^\prime) \Vert]
$$
where $f(x^\prime) \in \mathbb{R}^d$.And the norm of it is $L^2$ norm.

After abstraction, i transfer the problem to the title of this question,i.e,$\Vert\mathbb{E}[X]\Vert\leq \mathbb{E}[\Vert X\Vert]$ for any random vector $X$.

i have known that above inequality is hold on when the dismension of r.v is $1$(proven by jensen inequality).So i guess it is also right.

I have made some efforts as follows,above proposition is equivalent to prove
$$
\sqrt{\sum_i (\mathbb{E}[X_i])^2} \leq \mathbb{E}\Big[\sqrt{\sum_i X_i^2}\Big]
$$
but I have not found a good way to prove it,can u tell me the right way or point out the mistake made by me?

Thank for u advance!

Comment: This is called Minkowski inequality

Comment: @RichardChen Hi,Minkowski inequality is of the form $\| f + g\|_p \le \|f\|_p + \|g\|_p$. i don't know its relation to this question.Can u speak more precisly?

Comment: Show $‖⋅‖$ is convex and apply [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

Comment: @Hyperplane Great answer!thank for u help!

Comment: There is "integral Minkowski inequality" see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality

Comment: You can understand like this: $\mathbb{E}$ is a kind of summation, so  $\|\mathbb{E} X\|\approx\|\sum X_i\|\le \sum\| X_i\|\approx \mathbb{E}\|X\|$